# Parse JSON file with JavaScirpt

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON file with JavaScript. I've managed to open a local JSON file with JavaScript and print the keys of it with this code. I can't figure out how to get the values of each key. I want to get the `x, y, z` values of each key and assign them to variables in JavaScript.

script.js

```
function loadJSON(callback) {

var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xobj.open('GET', 'js/data.json', true);
xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

// .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in async mode so use a callback
        callback(xobj.responseText);

    }
};
xobj.send(null);

}

// Call to function with anonymous callback
loadJSON(function(response) {
// Do Something with the response e.g.
var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(response);

// Assuming json data is wrapped in square brackets as Drew suggests
    var keys = Object.keys(jsonresponse);
    console.log(keys[0]);
});
```

data.json

```
{
  "a": {
    "x": "12",
    "y": "2",
    "z": "17"
  },
  "b": {
    "x": "8",
    "y": "2",
    "z": "21"
  },
  "c": {
    "x": "9",
    "y": "3",
    "z": "17"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: If you have accessed a, b, c etc.  then just do a['x'], a['y'] and so on to get the next level values.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` does all the parsing for you. I presume you're asking how to loop the resulting object and the question does not really have anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, if you have accessed the top level keys (a, b, c etc.) then the next level (contained key-value pairs) can be accessed in the same manner.

```js
raw = '{ "a": { "x": "12", "y": "2", "z": "17" }, "b": { "x": "8", "y": "2", "z": "21" }, "c": { "x": "9", "y": "3", "z": "17" } }';
data = JSON.parse(raw);
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    value = data[key];
    console.log("Values inside: " + key)
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => console.log(key + "=" + value[key]));
})
```

Since both levels are Map data structure, the same can be accessed this way as well: `data['a']['x']`, `data['b']['x']` etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know how to access them keys individually. That;s what I wanted to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your result of json parse is a object so you just need to process it as object not array.

```
var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(response);

for(let data in jsonresponse) {
    for (let key in jsonresponse[data]) {
        let value = jsonresponse[data][key];
        console.log(key, value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yeah I can loop through keys with this code :)